# eShop version of Metroid Prime Trilogy freezes on WiiU

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, nintendo-eshop

I downloaded the eShop version of Metroid Prime Trilogy and played for a few hours.  I later moved it to a USB drive.  Now, I can get to the initial menus, pick a game, save file, etc., then the whole system freezes on the "now loading" screen.

I suspect somehow the game data got corrupted during the move, but I don't think the eShop supports anything like "verify game cache" on Steam.  Am I stuck deleting and re-downloading?  Can I do this without affecting my save data?

Comment: As far as I know the Wii U doesn't have a feature for verifying existing game content after installation, but it certainly does check it during installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of anything similar to "verify game cache" on the Wii U or any other console. However, you could try to move the game back to the internal storage to see if that fixes your problem.

If moving the game back to internal storage *does* fix your problem, there might be something wrong with your USB storage. However, if the problem persists, deleting and downloading the game once more may be the only solution left to you.

Luckily, it is possible to delete the game data without losing your save game. To do this, follow the steps listed below:

1. Open **System Settings**.
2. Select **Data Management**, which should be the second item from the left.
3. Select **Copy/Move/Delete Data**.
4. Choose the storage device on which the game is located.
5. Choose the game whose data you want to delete.
6. Choose **Metroid Prime Trilogy**. It should be listed as **Software** with a size of **7571 MB**.
   ***Do not*** choose **Shared save data**, because that's the save games ***you do not wish to delete!***
7. Touch the **Delete** button, confirm your choice, and wait patiently until the data is deleted. This process shouldn't take very long.
8. After the game data is deleted, your Wii U will ask you: "**Would you like to delete the save data too?**" Make sure you hit **Cancel** here. Your Wii U will notify you that "**The save data for this software will no longer be displayed in Data Management.**", meaning you'll have to switch to Wii mode to delete those save games. Don't worry, as soon as you've downloaded the game again, its save files will reappear in Data Management.
9. You may leave the **System Settings** and proceed to download the game anew.

Comment: Sorry it's taking so long to try your suggestion, I don't have enough system memory free to move Metroid over so I'm working on shuffling things around - Wii U memory operations take *forever* to complete!

Comment: Finally got a chance to free up some of the onboard storage and moved over Metroid.  It worked!  I'm not sure what that means -- every other game I've tried from the external drive works fine -- but I'll take it for the time being.  Thanks!